How to transfer a Windows 11 retail key from an old PC (with local accounts only) to a new PC?
I currently have Windows activated on a PC with only local accounts.
My system activation settings looks like the follows:

Output of slmgr /dli looks like the follows:

I prefer not logging into Windows using my Microsoft accounts, for privacy reasons.

Did you purchase the licence separately or did it come with your computer? If you have the key, then in theory there's nothing much stopping you re-using it. And to stop forced Microsoft accounts, disconnecting the lan/WiFi during setup usually enables local account creation.

You uninstall it from the current machine and reinstall it in the new machine.

Hey, if you down vote, please comment and let me know why. This is a legitimate question with no clear answer from windows document. Google search also leads to a bunch of incorrect/incomplete answers for my situation.

@NickSlash purchased separately. It's a retail key as stated in the title.

As far as I know, a retail key can be activated multiple times – there is a soft limit but it does not directly correspond to the number of licenses on that key, and Microsoft mostly seems to consider it the customer's responsibility to manage their own license compliance.
So there is no "license transfer" as such; you just activate the same key on the new PC, then uninstall Windows from the old one. (Or use slmgr.vbs to remove the product key from it, but I guess that no longer works with "digital license" activation. Howeve,r Reddit says that if the old PC remains in use and connected to the Internet, at some point it'll automatically go into "un-activated" status.)

The author should still be able to remove the retail license.

@Ramhound: Temporarily, maybe, but as soon as it becomes a "digital license", even one of the generic keys (from Microsoft's docs) would automatically activate it again.

Yes; Of course even before a system or machine could be linked to a MSA that was sort of the case. Windows 10 changed how Windows is activated in significant ways. Once installed with a license key once, that system can always run that version of Windows, and will be activated automatically.
